# How we plot the sum of two functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have those 2 functions:

```
f=[3 1 -5];
g=[-1 0 5];
```

I need to plot the sum of them, how can we do that in Matlab please ?

Answer (score 1):

f and g look like arrays to me (not functions as you say).

If you want to plot the sum of them... just plot the sum of them!

```
plot(f+g)   % couldn't be easier!
```